# addClass(''); problems again

Tags: javascript

I am writing an animation and I want to add class to the divs that are being created each time in the for loop but every time

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 function divCreater() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        document.createElement("div");
        let div = document.querySelectorAll("div");
        div.addClass('div');
        div.width = "(Math.random()*10)px";
        div.height = "(Math.random()*10)px";
        canvas.appendChild("div");
    }
};
divCreater();
```

I get the error that addClass is not a function

Comment: You can use something like `div.classList.add("div")`

Comment: `document.createElement("div");` won't do anything if you don't assign it to a variable and do something with it.

Comment: also, math.random() isn't going to do anything in quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `div.classList.add('div');` instead. Also `document.querySelector("div");` to just select one element.
You are also creating a div that you're not using. Do this instead:

```
let div = document.createElement("div");
/*let div = document.querySelectorAll("div");*/
```